# What's the difference between revokeCredentials and revokeToken?

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

`revokeCredentials`: Revokes access token and clears the credentials object

`revokeToken`: Revokes the access given to token.

What's the difference? There is no doc and sample for explaining these two methods [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ain't well documented.

`revokeToken` requires you pass a specific `accessToken` to the method:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L801

`revokeCredentials` accepts no arguments, and revokes the access token currently configured in the `OAuth2` instance:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L827

Hope this helps!